# PHPMailer Gmail summary

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

How can I make sure that Gmail (and other mediums) use my "text/plain" for the summary (see image below) and the "text/html" version for displaying when sending mails in PHP? Using PHPMailer's `altBody` did work for me before, but now Gmail only shows the first words used in the "text/html" version instead of using the "text/plain" one.

[image: Gmail messages with "summary"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, it's beyond your control, but you can play to their actions.
Gmail. Apple Mail, iOS mail, Outlook and others usually take the first non-markup text they find for that area, which is often referred to as a 'pre-header'. You can add some text to say whatever you like, then hide it in your HTML using CSS, for example:

```
...
<body>
<span style="display:none !important;">This will be invisible in the message, but shown in the message preview.</span>
<p>Dear xxx,</p>
...
```

As you've seen you don't have any control over the length that is displayed - e.g. mobile clients will usually display less than desktop ones - so I'd advise you to keep it short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Display none is not enough, some will continue to display it, like Outlook.

use this :

```
<!-- pre header -->
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;">your text </div>
```

Also, some use title tag, so think to complete it too